# Hidden Markov Model: Forward Algorithm implementation in Python

Tags: python, implementation, markov-hidden-model

I am learning Hidden Markov Model and its implementation for Stock Price Prediction. I am trying to implement the Forward Algorithm according to this [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b4f6/ce2ec24430110da27468f9ed1a17720ad8b8.pdf).

[image]

[Here](http://www.adeveloperdiary.com/data-science/machine-learning/forward-and-backward-algorithm-in-hidden-markov-model/) I found an implementation of the Forward Algorithm in Python.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

V = np.array([0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2]) 

# Transition Probabilities
a = np.array(((0.54, 0.46), (0.49, 0.51)))

# Emission Probabilities
b = np.array(((0.16, 0.26, 0.58), (0.25, 0.28, 0.47)))

# # Equal Probabilities for the initial distribution
pi = np.array((0.5, 0.5))

def forward(V, a, b, pi):
    alpha = np.zeros((V.shape[0], a.shape[0]))
    alpha[0, :] = initial_distribution * b[:, V[0]]

    for t in range(1, V.shape[0]):
        for j in range(a.shape[0]):
            alpha[t, j] = alpha[t - 1].dot(a[:, j]) * b[j, V[t]]

    return alpha

alpha = forward(V, a, b, pi)
```

But it seems to me that it does not include (c) and (d) steps from the algorithm. So I added them:

```
def forward(V, a, b, pi):
    p = 1
    alpha = np.zeros((V.shape[0], a.shape[0]))
    alpha[0, :] = pi * b[:, V[0]]

    for t in range(1, V.shape[0]):
        probability_of_observation = 0 #my code
        for j in range(a.shape[0]):
            alpha[t, j] = alpha[t - 1].dot(a[:, j]) * b[j, V[t]]
            probability_of_observation += alpha[t, j]  #my code
        p = p * probability_of_observation #my code

    return p #changed

p = forward(V, a, b, pi)  #changed
```

Does my code coincide with the given algorithm?

Comment: I am trying to do the exact thing as you (building an hmm from scratch). Is your code the complete algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this python library could help you: [hmmlearn](https://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

When I tried to build an hmm I used it and it worked well.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I am reviewing research paper and I need to understand the algorithm how it works. For me it is hard to understand the algorithm as mathematical notation. That's why I am trying to implement it in Python. If I use the library, I do not understand how the algorithm works.